# g++ relative paths

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I'm attempting to design a shared library of shared libraries using g++ with hopes of simplifying my compile scripts and easing my update process in the future, but I'm still novice at best with GNU tools and writing libraries, at that.  Can anyone provide advice on whether the following idea is possible with g++?

For convenience, consider the following file system layout:

```
main.cpp
libraryX/
libraryX/libX.so
libraryX/libraryY/
libraryX/libraryY/libY.so
libraryX/libraryZ/
libraryX/libraryZ/libZ.so
```

My goal is to be able to link indirectly using cascading relative paths.  For instance, main.cpp links to libraryX/libX.so, which links to libraryY/libY.so and libraryZ/libZ.so.  Is it possible to only link main.cpp to libX.so and use functions defined in libY.so and libZ.so?

If so, could you provide an example of the flags one would need to do so?  I've been trying variations of the following command using various sources from Google to no avail:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -Wl-rpath=libraryX -LlibraryX -lX.so main.o -o executable
```

Any guidance or references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more information on why you want that?

Comment: Linux distro build systems have been removing this link technique wherever they find it. Libraries and programs that use functions in library Y should always link Y. There are too many bugs caused by linking X, assuming it will always link Y, and then a change in X means Y isn't linked anymore.

Comment: @envu: I want it mainly for convenience, as I've designed my build scripts around the concept.  After thinking about this overnight, however, alternatives to this method seem not only imminent, considering Zan Lynx's comment, but also better in terms of design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this (even if you can figure out how).

When you link against `-lX`, the static linker must know all other shared libraries that are "part of this link". Since `-lY` is not on the link line, the static linker will either give you an error, or it must somehow figure out where `libY.so` is coming from. For the latter, it has to replicate the `RPATH` search that the runtime loader will perform. This replication is error prone (the static linker may not use the exact same algorithm) and best avoided.

Finally, your command line is totally wrong: `-shared` means you ask the linker for a shared library, but you are clearly trying to link an executable. You generally should not use `-fPIC` when linking an executable. Also, `-Wl-rpath=...` should be `-Wl,-rpath=...` (the comma is important).